# Java URLConnection.setRequestProperty in android studio doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: java, android, rest, android-studio, java-8

I looked at the source code for URLConnection.setRequestProperty in android studio and it doesn't seem like it sets anything:

```
public void setRequestProperty(String field, String newValue) {
        checkNotConnected();
        if (field == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("field == null");
        }
    }
```

and here is checkNotConnected():

```
private void checkNotConnected() {
        if (connected) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already connected");
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here? Because it seems like this method does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

URLConnection is an abstract class that's meant to be overridden by an extending class.  When you override that method, you should be making a call to super() prior to executing your own code.  With the code above, it will check for basic exceptions before executing the code of the overriding class.

Comment: Thanks for that. I checked the "extending class's" implementation -HttpURLConnection- for an implementation of setRequestProperty(), but there was none; and also that class is an abstract class too. Are you familiar with HttpURLConnection?